# jQuery submit() not firing when triggered from live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the form `#url_form` to be submitted when a URL is pasted into `#video_url`. The `.loading` class is added correctly, but the form still isn't being submitted.
Here's the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#url_form").live("paste", "#video_url", function(){
    $("#video_url").addClass("loading");
    $("#url_form").submit();
  });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts/get_video" data-remote="true" id="url_form" method="post">
   <input autofocus="autofocus" class="post-modal-url loading" id="video_url" name="video_url" placeholder="Paste a URL here" required="required" type="url">
</form>
```

the Rails form_tag:

```
 <%= form_tag get_video_posts_path, :remote => true, :id => "url_form"  do -%>
    <%= url_field_tag 'video_url', params[:video_url], :placeholder => "Paste a URL here", :required => true, :autofocus => true, :class => "post-modal-url" -%>
  <% end -%>
```

Comment: live is deprecated, long live [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: And for older versions use .delegate

Answer (score 3):

change

```
 $("url_form").submit();
```

to

```
$("#url_form").submit();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. `$("#url_form").submit()` doesn't work either.

Comment: a good way to trouble shoot these issues is to use the javascript debug tool that comes with chrome. you will usually see the problem immediately

Comment: Added HTML. Thanks, I do use the debug tool, but I just can't seem to solve this one.

Comment: "paste" works fine - it successfully adds the loading class to the input on paste. It's just the submit that doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking?

Comment: the form tag. post the html for the form tag

Comment: can you see the request going out in the network part of the debugger?

Comment: No. No request is being sent out.

Comment: put an alert after this: $("#video_url").addClass("loading"); does it show?

Comment: try stripping the form back to just an action and a method, and the input to just an id and a name